# How to select info from the latest record from a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a TABLE 1 like:

```html
First Name     Last Name      Birthyear       Modifieddate
John           Doe            1990            2/25/2011
John           Doe            1995            3/2/2011
```

where the latest record (ie the row with birthyear 1995) contains the most recent accurate information.

I would like to insert the 'correct' latest birthyear into another table.

The original query I wrote was: `

```html
UPDATE TABLE2
SET Birthyear = TABLE1.Birthyear FROM
TABLE 1 JOIN TABLE 2 ON TABLE1.First_name = TABLE2.First_name
AND TABLE1.Last_name = TABLE2.Last_name
```

but this inserts the birthyear (1990) from the first record.

How do I modify the query so that it inserts the correct "most recent" info?

Comment: Does your table have an ID or update date, or something else that would indicate which row is more recently added? (assuming you don't always want the latest birthyear)

Comment: Yes, it includes a 'modifieddate' as I just added above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `cross apply`:

```
update t2 set birthyear = ca.birthyear
from Table2 t2
cross apply(select top 1 birthyear
            from Table1 t1
            where t1.firstname = t2.firstname and 
                  t1.lastname = t2.lastname 
            order by t1.Modifieddate desc) ca
```

Comment: It appears that your `lastname` is misspelled in the cross apply.

Comment: This assumes that the latest `birthyear` is the most recent modification.  The OP added in his edit that there is another column called `Modifieddate` in the Table 1. The OP's one example is admittedly not much to go off, but it could very well be that the most recent modification has an earlier `birthyear`. I have edited your answer to fix this issue.

Comment: @Synergist, yes correct. I was not notified by update...Thanks

Comment: This answer works, thanks! I am not familiar with cross apply, but I will research it to figure out why this works.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the most current `birthyear` based on latest `modified_date` and update it on another table like this:

```
;WITH t1
AS (
    SELECT first_name
        ,last_name
        ,max(birthyear) recent_birthyear
        ,max(modified_date) last_modified_date
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY first_name
        ,last_name
    )
UPDATE t2
SET t2.Birthyear = t1.recent_birthyear
FROM TABLE2 t2
JOIN t1 ON t1.First_name = t2.First_name
    AND t1.Last_name = t2.Last_name

SELECT *
FROM table2
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/519df5/9)